# How to setup correct .htaccess for laravel app on subdomain?

Tags: apache-2.2, routing, .htaccess, redirect, laravel

I moved my Laravel application from the development localhost to an internet production subdomain.
On localhost everything works. But when I move app to subdomain it seems .htaccess can not handle redirects correctly.
When i type to browser `sub.mydomain.com` it redirect to `sub.mydomain.com/public`. Main webpage renders. But when i go to login page it returns 500 error. route is now `sub.mydomain.com/public/login`

It works only when i manualy type `sub.mydomain.com/public/index.php/login`

I do not know why is this happens, but on localhost it works fine.

My root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

And my /public .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Can you advise me how to properly configure htaccess to make it work properly?

Comment: When you get a 500 error, read the error log in the server. It contains a clear error message about the problem.

Comment: Share us the logs in /var/log/apache2/error.log. Also checkout your rewrite module is enabled or not. Run the following command if not:-
a2enmod rewrite

Answer (score 0):

This is my .htaccess configuration I'm using inside public folder


Options -MultiViews

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Redirection from http to https :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName yourdomain.com
  ServerAlias www.yourdomain.com
 
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public

  Redirect Permanent / https://yourdomain.com/

  ....
  ....

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName yourdomain.com
  ServerAlias www.yourdomain.com
 
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public

  Redirect permanent http://www.yourdomain.com/ https://yourdomain.com

  ....
  ....

 ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
 CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks!